# npm install -g when using nvm

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I'm using nvm to be able to switch node versions but when I try and install a global package with `npm install -g` it keeps installing to `/Users/<username>/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/` even though doing `node -v` shows version 9.10.0

Basically when I change node version using `nvm use ...` I want my global packages to go to the correct node version.

Thanks for any help

Comment: The behavior is explained in the nvm docs: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#migrating-global-packages-while-installing - although it might not exactly mimic the behavior you described

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it isn't working. I tried the `--reinstall-packages-from=` flag and even tried editing the `default-packages` in re-installing 8.10.0 and neither worked. It's still installing to 8.9.4 no matter what I do. Worth noting that I don't have a system node version so that's not the issue. Anything else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

The issue can most probably be with the NodeJS installation via nvm or the nvm.

The best solution can be to completely **uninstall** the nvm ( which'll eventually remove NodeJS alongside npm and if not, manually remove it using synaptic package manager or terminal) and **reinstall** it again.

To remove nvm:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvm && sudo apt-get purge nvm
```

To reinstall nvm again,

[follow this link](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)